# Searching for Annotations in Methods using Scala

Tags: scala, annotations

The following code fails to compile (`Output` is not of type `java.reflect.annotation.Annotation`):

```
class Output(val name : String) extends Annotation

class Block {
  def outputs {
    for {
      method <- this.getClass.getMethods
      val a = method.getAnnotation(classOf[Output])
      if a != null
    } {
      println(a.name)
    }
  }
}

class Arithmetic[T: Numeric](val A: Connector[T], val B: Connector[T]) extends Block {
  @Output("Sum")        def Sum  = new Connector({ A.Value + B.Value })
  @Output("Difference") def Diff = new Connector({ A.Value - B.Value })
  @Output("Multiply")   def Mul  = new Connector({ A.Value * B.Value })
}
```

Is there any way to achieve runtime reflection on the annotated members?

Comment: You should indicate what your error is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is no way to achieve this in Scala (yet), and thus we should resort to using a Java class as such:

```
import java.lang.annotation.*;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Output {
    public String value();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `Block.getClass` should be `classOf[Block]`. `getClass` works on instances.

(java equivalent: `x.getClass` <=> `x.getClass()`. `classOf[X]` <=> `X.class`. C# equivalent: `x.getClass` <=> `x.GetType()`. `classOf[X]` <=> `typeof(X)`)

Comment: Thx, but I actually wanted this.getClass. Even so, the error remains.

Comment: That's why you should really tell what your error is. Makes things easier than looking at the code and guessing where there might be a problem